# Awk cross reference 2 files

Tags: awk

I have 2 files which both have 2 columns. I wish to remove lines from 1.txt if the same column is in 2.txt.

Example -

1.txt (contains)

```
example:test
example2:test2
example3:test3
```

2.txt contains (contains)

```
example:example
example2:example
example3:example
example4:example
example5:example
```

so in 1.txt on column 1 the entries are the same as 2.txt, so expected output in this scenario would be

```
example4:example
example5:example
```

removed content -

```
example:test
example2:test2
example3:test3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem description could be clearer, but based on the example I think you want this:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR { d[$1]=1; next } !($1 in d) { print $0 }' 1.txt 2.txt
```

The `-F:` argument says "treat the colon character ':' as the column separator".  (By default `awk` treats runs of whitespace as the column separator.)

The second argument is an `awk` program that says

```
IF this line is from the first input file THEN
    In a dictionary named `d`, create an item whose key is the first column of the input line and whose value is 1
    Skip the rest of the program move on to process the next line

(because of the "skip to next line" above we only do this for lines from the second file)
IF the dictionary named `d` has no item whose whose key is the first column of this line THEN
    Print this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below command works perfectly

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0];next}($0 in a) {print $0}' 1.txt 2.txt
```